# user-error: Minibuffer window is not active

Tags: recover

I want to recover a file from system failure

```
M-x recover-file
```

It did not restore the auto-saved file, but to throw an error:

```
/var/folders/n8/dz3thx0x4sd2p8zdqyqbflrc0000gn/T/#!Users!gaowei!desktop!pubrepo!org!projects.org# not current
user-error: Minibuffer window is not active
Mark set
<s-double-drag-mouse-1> is undefined
```

I definitely  cannot read the info at the current level.

How could I solve the problem?

Comment: The text you show does not look like what comes when Emacs "throws an error", so you might want to clarify exactly what those four lines are (where did you take them from?) and what happened between the moment you hit RET (after `M-x recvover-file`) and the moment you found that text.

Comment: What @Stefan said. Try to provide a step-by-step recipe, saying what you did at each step, what you saw, and what you expected to see instead. And please start from `emacs -Q` (no init file).